# How to cite guide that doesn't have a year?

Tags: citations, citation-style

I have to cite [this guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mediation/vignettes/mediation.pdf) in one of my papers using the APA citation style.

How to cite it inline?

Zotero is inserting the citation like "(Tingley et al., n.d.)" because it doesn't have a year.

But I don't like the "n.d." part.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but it seems that the guide in question has also been formally published https://imai.fas.harvard.edu/research/files/mediationR2.pdf

Comment: @jnanin thanks, I think I'll cite that one, although I think it's less updated than the CRAN one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whether you like it or not, the APA style [requires](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/missing-information) you to write "n.d." instead of the missing date.

However, when you examine the file properties of the referenced document, you can see that it was compiled on 13 September 2019. I couldn't find an authoritative source on this, but it might be fair to date the reference accordingly.

How your citation manager handles missing dates is irrelevant. What matters is what the citation style requires. In this case, your citation manager did provide the correct output, in other cases it might not.